# Can't load BitmapImage from bitmap ( code attached )

Tags: silverlight

I trying to load BitmapImage from bmp file. 
When i load png or jpg => this code work with no problem. 
But when i trying to load bmp file - i get exception.

The exception information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

The code:

```
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Multiselect = false,
            Filter = "Image(*.png; *.jpg; *.bmp;)| *.png; *.jpg; *.bmp;"
        };

        if( dialog.ShowDialog() == true )
        {
            using( System.IO.Stream stream = dialog.File.OpenRead() )
            {
                byte[] img = new byte[ stream.Length ];
                stream.Read( img , 0, img .Length );

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource( stream );               // Here i have the exception
                itemImage.Source = image;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight does not support the Windows bitmap (BMP) format. Only JPG and PNG. *The use of the name BitmapImage refers to the generic bitmap term rather than the specific file format.*

JPG is the best format for photographic images and PNG the best format for other images as it has half-decent alpha channel support (unlike bitmaps and GIFs).

To load bitmap files (assuming you really need to) there are libraries about.